# python accessing another function variable error

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters

I am trying to get input from one function and dispaying it in another function but i could not get the expected result

```
class Base(object):

    def user_selection(self):
        self.usr_input = input("Enter any choice")
        user_input = self.usr_input
        return user_input

    def switch_selection(user_input):
        print user_input


b = Base()

b.user_selection()
b.switch_selection()
```

When i execute this program i get

```
Enter any choice1
<__main__.Base object at 0x7fd622f1d850>
```

I should get the value which i entered but i get

```
<__main__.Base object at 0x7fd622f1d850>
```

How could i get the value which i entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     def switch_selection(user_input):
>         print user_input
>
> ..
>
> b.switch_selection()
> ```

You may notice that you're not passing any argument into `switch_selection` when calling it, yet you're expecting to receive one argument. That's something of a cognitive disconnect there. You happen to actually receive an argument though, which is `b`. An object method in Python receives its object instance as its first parameter. The argument you're receiving is not `user_input`, it's `self`. That's what you're printing, that's the output you're seeing.

Two possibilities to fix this:

```
class Base(object):
    def user_selection(self):
        self.user_input = input("Enter any choice")

    def switch_selection(self):
        print self.user_input
```

or:

```
class Base(object):
    def user_selection(self):
        return input("Enter any choice")

    def switch_selection(self, user_input):
        print user_input


b = Base()
input = b.user_selection()
b.switch_selection(input)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this Code Working perfect for me,

```
class Base(object):

    def user_selection(self):
        self.usr_input = input("Enter any choice")
        user_input = self.usr_input
        return user_input

    def switch_selection(self,user_input):
        print user_input


b = Base()

g=b.user_selection()
b.switch_selection(g)
```